# Desativar link e button após o click

Tags: php, button, link

Já dei uma pesquisada aqui e em outros sites porem não encontrei uma resposta que se aplique de forma correta ao meu cenário.
A ideia é a seguinte tenho duas paginas uma com um link e outra com um button a do link chama uma pagina em php que executa uma conexão em um linux e dentro do linux roda alguns scripts, até ai tudo ok.
A pagina com o button tem um form usando o metodo post com action em branco para chamar ela mesmo, dentro dessa pagina tenho um if que verifica se a variavel _POST é true se sim ela conecta no linux e executa outro script.
Em ambos os casos esta funcionando perfeitamente, porem quando o usuário clica a pagina começa a carregar e só após a conexão com o linux e execução do script ela mostra o output na tela, o navegador começa a carregar certinho porem alguns usuários que não tem paciência estão clicando múltiplas vezes no link e botão.

A minha ideia é a seguinte, quando o usuário click no link ou no botão preciso remover ou desativar eles da pagina para evitar que o usuário click novamente.

De preferencia queria fazer isso com javascript mas se tiver algum outra forma que tenha o mesmo resultado também é valido.

Essa seria a duvida, como faço para desativar ou remover o link e botão da pagina após o click do usuário sem interromper com a execução natural da pagina?

Comment: não pode simplesmente adicionar o atributo "disabled" ou o estilo "display:none" ou "visibility: hidden"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão, que eu acho melhor, para que o usuário saiba que existe uma ação em andamento, não seria remover ou esconder o elemento da página, mas alterar o seu comportamento e o texto.

Ao clicar no elemento, seja ele um link `<a>` ou botão, você pode desativá-lo e alterar o texto para algo do tipo `"Enviando..."`, `"Aguarde..."` ou `"Processando..."`.

Você pode fazer isso usando `onclick`. No caso dos links `<a>`, você pode desabilitar o click usando a propriedade `pointer-events: none`, e no caso dos botões, adicionando o atributo `disabled`.

Ficaria assim em ambos os casos:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="this.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; this.textContent = 'Enviando...'">Link</a>
<br>
<button onclick="this.disabled = true; this.textContent = 'Enviando...'">Enviar</button>
```

Repare que depois do primeiro clique, ambos os elementos ficam desabilitados para novos cliques. No `href` do link coloquei a hash `#` só para exemplo. Você irá colocar nele a URL normal de destino.

Comment: Excelente!
O <a> consegui fazer certinho agora o problema está com o button, pois ele está dentro de um form se faço da forma que me falou ele desabilita o button porem não envia o form.

Comment: Tentei fazer com onsubmit="" porem acontece a mesma coisa não envia o form =/

Comment: Tente colocando um setTimeout: `<button onclick="setTimeout('this.disabled = true', 10); this.textContent = 'Enviando...'">Enviar</button>`

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou perfeitamente, você é foda Sam.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode estabelecer um COOKIE (via JavaScript) e em seguida estabelecer um setINterval que irá verificar se o cookie existe, se ele existir você desabilita os elementos que você quer.